Как обработать кнопки ReplyKeyboard со списком городов, чтобы при нажатии бот выдавал информацию, из словаря словарей. Aiogram
Решил попытаться самостоятельно написать телеграм-бот на питоне с помощью aiogram. Задача следующая: при старте появляется приветствие и 2 обычные кнопки (Список городов и еще одна). При нажатии на "Список..." появляется новая обычная клавиатура со списком городов:

До этого момента все самостоятельно как-то получилось. Теперь встал вопрос. У меня сделан отдельным файлом словарь городов, которые являются словарями:
cities = {
    'Владивосток': {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":"value3"
    },

    'Волгоград': {
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":"value3"
    }, ...

Не могу понять, каким образом оформить обработку нажатий на клавиши. Получилось самым простым вариантом, когда введенное пользователем сообщение явным образом сравнивается с именем города:
    @router.message(F.text.lower() == "владивосток")
    async def city_values(message: Message):
        for v in cities["Владивосток"].values():
            await message.answer(v)

Но в этом случае мне придется кучу обработок писать, и если предположить добавление новых городов, то каждый раз придется новую обработку добавлять. Есть ли способ прогнать через цикл? Или может еще варианты, которые я не смог найти в связи с тем, что я новичок.

Ну видимо нужно не прошивать конкретный город в параметрах раутера. А смотреть в обработчике, что-то типа if text.capitalize() in cities: for v in cities[text].values(): ... Как в боте текст сообщения смотреть я не знаю, я тут про словари в питоне чисто подсказываю.

Большое спасибо! Казалось бы несколько раз просматривал подобные конструкции, но только после Вашего, @CrazyElf, совета дошло, как это использовать. Получилось не сразу, т.к. опыта мало, но подогнал решение под ответ!)

После подсказки, подогнал решение под ответ следующим образом:
@router.message(F.text.lower())
async def city_values(message: Message):
    input_text = message.text
    if input_text in cities:
        for v in cities[input_text].values():
            await message.answer(v)
    else:
        await message.answer("Выберите город из списка, пожалуйста")

Возможно кто-то подскажет решение получше, буду очень благодарен!

А с большими/маленькими буквами разобрались? Надёжнее всего было бы в одном регистре чтобы и в словаре города были и то, что вы ищете чтобы было в этом же регистре. .capitalize() делает первую букву большой, остальные маленькими, если что.

А вообще тут просто нужно знать, что когда делается проверка строка in словарь, то это тоже самое, что строка in словарь.keys(), это фича Питона такая, которую просто нужно помнить, что там берутся ключи по факту.

Я как-то на регистр даже внимания не обратил. Я сперва сообщение от пользователя загоняю в нижний регистр (хотя по идее это не обязательно в данном случае), а он все равно корректно поиск по словарю делает. Получается ему будто все равно. Интересно...

Такого не может быть. Проверьте. Скорее всего @router.message(F.text.lower()) в итоге проверяет только то, что текст не пустой. Преобразованная строка никуда дальше не попадает, остаётся с сообщении в том же регистре, в котором её ввели. Так что с введёнными в другом регистре городами будет проблема, они не найдутся в словаре. Ну, разве что у вас в словаре и так и так города записаны... А, стоп, если у вас выбор из меню, то если в меню города в нужном регистре (а может из самого словаря сгенерированы), то делать ничего и не нужно... Если не возможен ручной ввод, не из меню.

Попытался разобраться в документации, но где искать взаимодействие кнопок и F (магический фильтр) так и не понял. Судя по всему, Вы правы, и дело в том что на кнопках текст из словаря и ответ от пользователя ожидаем только через кнопку. Приводить к нижнему регистру даже не обязательно, проверил у себя, и без .lower() работает
